# if then else velocity

Tags: if-statement, velocity

During my searching, I would like your help on this problem :

I have this code

```
#set($infos=$tracker.getTrackingInfos("$query.reference.toUpperCase()"))

            infos : $infos

            #if($infos)

                #set($e = $tracker.getEnvoi($query.reference.toUpperCase().trim()))
                #set($destinataire = $e.destinataire) 
                #set($expediteur = $e.expediteur)   

                #set($dbBoxtale.ope = $e.envoi_reference.substring(0,4))
                #set($operateur = $dbBoxtale.operateur_by_code)         

                <!---------- INFORMATIONS ---------->
                #set($infos=$tracker.getTrackingInfos("${e.envoi_numfact}${e.envoi_reference}"))
                #set($reference = $!e.envoi_opeinfos)
                #parse("/inc/tracking_display.inc")

                <!---------- ORDER RECAP ---------->
                    <div class="row ">
                        <h2 class="mt20">Récapitulatif de votre commande : $query.reference</h2>
                        <div class="bg-top-box pl20 mb20 row p15">
                            <p class="title-border s14 light pt10"><img class="mb5 mr5" src="$resourcesData.img.ico-box2" alt="" />Contenu de votre envoi</p>
                            <p class="pt10 pl15">

                                #foreach($grp in $e.groupe_objets)
                                    #set($display = $e.envoi_type.toLowerCase())

                                    #if($e.type_envoi == "Objet lourd") 
                                        #set($display = "encombrant")
                                    #end

                                    <strong>$grp.nb 
                                        #if($e.groupe_objet == 1 || $e.envoi_type == "Colis") 
                                            $display
                                        #else 
                                            ${display}s
                                        #end
                                    </strong> - $grp.poids kg - <strong>Dimensions</strong> $grp.longueur cm x $grp.largeur cm #if($e.envoi_type != "Pli") x $grp.hauteur cm #end <br />
                                    <strong>Contenu :</strong> $e.envoi_typeobjet

                                #end

                            <p class="text-warning pl15 pb10 pt10">
                                <img alt="" src="$resourcesData.img.ico-alert-small">
                                Si les dimensions et poids sont erronés, votre envoi sera bloqué par le transporteur.
                            </p>

                        </div><!--end bg-top-box pt15 pl20 mb20 row p15 -->

                    </div>

            #elseif(!$infos)

                <img class="" src="$resourcesData.img.ico-warning"  alt=""> 


            #end

        #end
```

In fact, I am trying to type a reference and if the reference exists in the DB, the area "#if" is executed and if the reference doesn't exist in DB the "#elseif" is executed.

But now when I type a wrong reference It doesn't enter in the #elseif, I don't know why.

If you have idea...

Ale

Comment: In fact I have to test $tracker.getTrackingInfos not $infos

Comment: Can you simplify the example a bit? There's a lot of extraneous stuff in there.